# ToList() method using Single() linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem with ToList() method and basically I'm trying to make a function that will return a var linq query convert to a list and here the the function.

```
 List<UsersTabPage> GetFirstOne()
 {
    using (MCMDataContext db = new MCMDataContext())
    {
        MCM.User user = new MCM.User();
        var firstone = (from oneUser in db.Users
                        where oneUser.ID == user.ID
                        select oneUser).Single();
        return firstone.ToList();
    }
 }
```

Here are the librarys that I'm currently using in the application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
```

If there is any library needed, Please comment below or post an answer.
Here is the error.

'MCM.User' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'MCM.User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
If you know any answer please post it below. Thank you.

Comment: NET Framework version?

Comment: You are using .Single() and then .ToList(). So if you want to do it that way, wrap your item in a list

Comment: Stop editing the title of your question.  It's actively harmful to remove the actual title of the question.

Comment: I WILL BECAUSE LIKE THAT WILL I GET -VOTES AND REP GOES OFF.

Comment: Please put the original title to the question to help people to find the question and to solve the problem you had with the solutions you received.

Comment: THIS QUESTION MADE ME LOSE ALL MY REP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling `Single()`, which means you've got *one* result. `ToList()` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you want to create a list with just that one element, you *could* write:

```
return new List<UsersTabPage> { firstone };
```

... but it seems more likely that *either* you should get rid of the `Single()` call *or* you should just make your method return `UsersTabPage`.

On the other hand, it looks like the type of `firstone` is a `User`, not a `UsersTabPage` - we don't know anything about the relationship between those two types, so you probably want to revisit that aspect, too.

Comment: Basically I'm new to Linq to Sql and WPF and I want to get the first record from the database using linq to sql and I tried this query but thanks for the help and how do I get the data after I remove the single then?

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf: Well if you only want one record, you shouldn't remove the `Single` call - but given that you've got one object of type `MCM.User`, how do you intend to turn that into a `List<UsersTabPage>`? What *is* a `UsersTabPage`? Are you sure that you really want this method to return a `List<UsersTabPage>`? (It sounds unlikely to me...)

Comment: UsersTabPage is the XAML layout file and I am trying to get the first record from the database and If there is a better method that can you recommend me to get the first record using linq?

Comment: @ShariqMusharaf: Well I'd just use `var record = db.Users.Single(u => u.ID == user.ID);`... it's odd that you're getting the ID from a newly created default record, mind you. It sounds like you're mixing up UI and storage logic if you've got a method hitting the database but trying to return a list of UI elements though - I suggest you take a big step back and look at the architecture of your app.

Answer (score 3):

You call `.Single()` at the end of your LINQ statement, so that statement returns an `MCM.User` object and not an `IEnumerable`. Remove the `.Single()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning single object of type `UsersTabPage` so you cannot call `ToList()` because `ToList()` can be called on Collections,it cannot be called on single instance which is not Collection.
You can use `Take()` following way:

```
var firstone = (from oneUser in db.Users
                  where oneUser.ID == user.ID
                  select oneUser).Take(1).ToList();
return firstone;
```

or mores simple using lambda syntax:

```
var firstone = db.Users.Where(oneUser => oneUser.ID == user.ID)
                       .Take(1).ToList();
return firstone;
```

Comment: What does Take() does?

Comment: it will just give the first element collection but it will also be a collection with 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

YOu got Single object, which list do you expect!

```
firstone. = ....Single();
firstone.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work...by selecting `.Single()` on the LINQ query you get only one result, and therefore cannot convert one element to a list.

If you want to convert to a list, remove the `.Single()`.

This is exactly my point when I mention to people that `var` should be used sparingly: this entire issue could have been avoided with proper explicit type-defining.

```
List<UsersTabPage> GetFirstOne()
{
    using (MCMDataContext db = new MCMDataContext())
    {
        MCM.User user = new MCM.User();
        var firstone = (from oneUser in db.Users
                  where oneUser.ID == user.ID
                  select oneUser);
        return firstone.ToList();
    }
}
```

OR

```
List<UsersTabPage> GetFirstOne()
{
    using (MCMDataContext db = new MCMDataContext())
    {
        MCM.User user = new MCM.User();
        return (from oneUser in db.Users
                  where oneUser.ID == user.ID
                  select oneUser).ToList();
    }
}
```